# SQLCipher compiled error

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlcipher

Just follow the tutorial http://sqlcipher.net/ios-tutorial

however,when i complied my App in debug mode,the error message is

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
_SecRandomCopyBytes", referenced from:
  _sqlcipher_cc_random in libsqlcipher.a(sqlite3.o)
```

what the problem,please help me,thanks.

Comment: You probably forgot to add the Security.framework to your project.

Comment: you are right!Thank you !But i have a question here,the sub project "sqlcipher.xcodeproj" has the security.framework involved already,my app is using the libsqlcipher.a ,why i need the security.framework added into Frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

thanks to `Martin R`

libsqlcipher.a static library compiled upon the "Security.Framework"，

So to use this static library,you project must add link library of "Security.framework"